# Use getter/setter methods in interface

Tags: java, interface

My question is how can I write setter/getter methods and static fields in an interface and implement it in another class.

An example:

```
public interface MyInterface {
int number = 0;

public int setNumber(int num);{

 }
}

// Use it

public MyClass implements MyInterface{

 ...

public int setNumber(int num) {
   number = num;   // Error, Why?
 }
}
```

I get error on `number = num` but it get no error in the `setName(...)` method!

Comment: Besides all the correct answers, setNumber method currently must return an int value or it will no compile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Interface Usage Guidelines -- Are getters and setters in an interface bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130294/java-interface-usage-guidelines-are-getters-and-setters-in-an-interface-bad)

Comment: you can use abstract class for this purpose

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You cannot define *instance fields* in interfaces (unless they are constant - `static final` - values, thanks to [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13878520/17713)), since they're part of the *implementation* only. Thus, only the *getter and setter* are in the interface, whereas the field comes up in the implementation.

And `setNumber` should return a `void` instead of `int`. For getting I suggest you to add `int getNumber()`.

```
public interface MyInterface {
  void setNumber(int num); // public is implicit in interfaces
  int getNumber();         // obviously
}

public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
  private int number = 0;
  
  public void setNumber(int num) { this.number = num; }
  public int getNumber() { return this.number; }
}
```

As you can see, only `setNumber` is part of `MyInterface`. Consumers do not need to know about how the number is stored, therefore it is an implementation detail.

Besides, in Java you name classes and interfaces in `PascalCase` rather than `camelCase`.

Comment: Or rather, the only fields you can declare in interfaces are constants.

Comment: You should think it twice to see if you really want to put a setter in an `interface`. Given you don't know the implementation, you are probably saying too much if you force them to have a setter - dummy or constant implementations wouldn't need them.

Comment: I agree. However, the OP already had the "lonely" setter, with I think is less common than a getter only. That's why I added both.

Answer (score 9):

When you define a value in an interface it is implicitly `public static final`  i.e. it's immutable and not an instance field.

Interfaces are used for defining a contract, not behaviour so it doesn't make sense to insist that all implementations have this field.

BTW You can do this if you have an `abstract class` as well as or instead of an `interface`

Answer (score 4):

Interface can not contain method body definition and field are `public`, `final` and `static` by default which normally use for constant declaration. It will be defined where you are going to implement this interface.

> In the Java programming language, an interface is a reference type, similar to a class, that can contain only constants, method signatures, and nested types. There are no method bodies. Interfaces cannot be instantiated—they can only be implemented by classes or extended by other interfaces.
>
> [ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)

But `abstract class` can contain concrete method as well as abstract method.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change the fields declared in an interface as they are by deafulat `public static final`.

You see `final` so they cannot be changed once initialized.

And in an interface you cannot give implementation of a method as you are doing in your code.

just put `;` after the method signature and not `{}` (not even empty `{}`) :

```
public int setNumber(int num);
```

Answer (score 3):

Fields in `interface` are by default **public static final** i.e., constants.remember you have already initialized `number` in your `interface` and trying to change its value in your implementing class which breaks the laws of final variables .

From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

> A variable can be declared final. A final variable may only be
>   assigned to once. Declaring a variable final can serve as useful
>   documentation that its value will not change and can help avoid
>   programming errors.
>
> It is a compile-time error if a final variable is assigned to unless
>   it is definitely unassigned (§16) immediately prior to the assignment.

Also methods in interface are by default public abstract. i dont understand your method signature in your interface. it should be something like below.

```
public void method();
```