# Is it fine to use getter & setter methods in a interface

Tags: java, methods, get, desktop-application

I am creating a java app and wanted to know that is it a good practice to use getter and setter method in a interface. The interface would just be used for 1 class and not multiple. My app is not even a MVC app but should really follow java design patterns.
Also, when implementing a basic java app, how can I see that the developer cares about java design.

Comment: This is one google search away: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130294/java-interface-usage-guidelines-are-getters-and-setters-in-an-interface-bad

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, if you're using it in multiple places. It depends on context. MVC is irrelevant to using accessors and mutators (e.g. getters and setters). Finally, if you are the developer; check if you care!

Answer (score 0):

**interface defines a contract.**

It can be anything. You just define the methods that needs to be implemented by any class that is inherited.

Its a good practice to use interface but sometime **[fever composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)**.